# Why does MethodInfo.Invoke wrap exceptions in a TargetInvocationException?

Tags: .net, reflection

I'm asking this out of curiosity rather than due to a real need to know, but I can't think of any good reasons for `MethodInfo.Invoke` to wrap its exceptions.

Were it to let them pass unwrapped, debugging such exceptions in Visual Studio would be a tiny bit easier - I wouldn't have to ask VS to stop on first-chance exceptions to see the current state at the source of exception. The stack trace would presumably show [external code] just after the call to `Invoke`, but so what.

Am I missing some important function that this wrapping provides that would not be possible had `Invoke` let exceptions pass unwrapped?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Am I missing some important function
>   that this wrapping provides that would
>   not be possible had Invoke let
>   exceptions pass unwrapped?

Yes. One argument is to be able to **distinguish between exception throw by the target method and exception thrown by the reflection mechanism itself**. Ex. the `ArgumentException` can be thrown from the reflection mechanism *or* the target method -- these are two different meta-level.

Another argument is the **contract of the `invoke` method itself**. In Java, the `invoke` method is allowed to throw only the exception declared in the method signature. Arbitrary exception would simply not obey the signature and need then to be wrapped. This argument doesn't hold for C# as is, but is still valid. The `invoke` method has a contract defined in the doc which you could not rely on, if target exception were thrown as is.

Comment: Your first argument is a bit crude. This would mean that all methods should wrap exceptions coming from calls to other methods to distinguish between them. There are mechanisms to see where the exception comes from: If Invoke itself throws, the stack trace points into M$ code. Additionally the type of the exception gives a hint.

Answer (score -1):

If there is a situation, where the TargetInvocationException can be thrown without the invoked method throwing and exception, it makes sense. I'm not sure if there's such a case.